# php- File Type Restriction not working

Tags: php

I am trying to restrict Image file type to only JPG,PNG,JPEG but this script is not allowing any file (even if its above mentioned formats) and the NO FILE selected part is also not working. though I am selecting the file it's still alerting you have to select profile picture(the JS alert msg mentioned in the code) what's wrong in the code?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //this part is part of the HTML form. please neglect this. this's working

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $email =$_POST['email'];





    if($_FILES["profpic"]["tmp_name"] =="") { //even $_FILES['profpic']['name']=="" is not working
        echo "<script>alert('You have to upload Profile Picture.');</script>";
        exit();
    }
    //$check = getimagesize($_FILES["profpic"]["tmp_name"]);

    if(getimagesize($_FILES["profpic"]["tmp_name"])) {
    echo "<script>alert('Invalid Image.');</script>";
    exit();
    } 

    if ($_FILES["profpic"]["size"] > 1000000) {
    echo "<script>alert('Your Image is too big,Maximum Image Size is 1MB');</script>";
    exit();
    }

    $type = $_FILES['profpic']['type'];
    $allowedImageType = array('image/jpg','image/png','image/jpeg');

    function imageType($image){
        global $allowedImageType;
        if(in_array($image,$allowedImageType))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    if(!imageType($type)) {
     echo "<script>alert('Only JPG,JPEG,PNG Image Allowed!');</script>";
     exit();
    }
        //the code if everything went right-------------------------
    $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO users(id,username,password,email) VALUES('','$user','$pass','$email')");

    $id = $conn->insert_id;

    $picname = "$id.jpg";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profpic']['tmp_name'], "images/$picname");
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('noti').innerHTML='Account Creation Successful. <a href=\'login.php\'>Click here</a> to Login';</script>";
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$_FILES['profpic']['type']`?

Comment: Remember `in_array()` is case sensitive.

Comment: @Stefan if I use tmp_name still it's not working

Comment: @HenryTK extensions are in lowercase. then why it's not working?

Comment: @AnuranBarman var dump your $_FILES['profpic'] here so we can help you in the good direction.

Comment: (And hope that you used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.)

Comment: opppss... sorry I forgot to add enctype.. sorry everyone for wasting your time.. I am really sorry. did not expect that I can forget to add that one. sorry !!

Comment: it seems something is still wrong. it's still showing the image format restriction error though I have selected a JPG file. and fake image, getimagesize is not working too (I changed the extension of a PDF file to jpg, hope by fake image, w3schools.com meant this)